# How to restrict access some part of module in ZendFramework 2 (i.e. only administrator can do some actions)

Tags: authentication, zend-framework2

so!

I have a question: how to allow access some part of module only for adminisitrator, for example.

For example, I have module album. It has controllers index, delete, add, edit, full. I want full and index controller be available for all roles, but edit, delete and add action only for administrators.

What module I have to use to do that? I found Zend\Authentification.

Table is: `username`, `password`, `role`.

How to authentificate user?:

```
// do the authentication
$auth = Zend_Auth::getInstance();
$result = $auth->authenticate($authAdapter);
if ($result->isValid()) {
    // success: store database row to auth's storage
    // system. (Not the password though!)
    $data = $authAdapter->getResultRowObject(null, 'password');
    $auth->getStorage()->write($data);
    $this->_redirect('/');
} else {
    // failure: clear database row from session
    $this->view->message = 'Login failed.';
}
```

After that I will get access to user data, for example, by:

```
Zend_Auth::getInstance()->getIdentity()->username;
```

So, in action, in which I want to restrict access I just need to use:

```
if(Zend_Auth::getInstance()->getIdentity()->role == admin) {
   redirect("auth/login");
}
```

Right?

The questions:

1. Is my suggestion about how to check user role in each contoller correct?
2. Do I understand correctly how to work with Zend\Authentification and restrict access to some actions? So in future I will just use same for each action, right?

Additional question: Does `Acl`module uses for managing permissions? So Acl is needed to help Zend_Auth with permissions, right?

Comment: Zend_Auth is Zend Framework component not Zend Framework 2 as You're tagged this topic.

Next note is that Zend_Auth is for authentication not authorization. Authentication is determining whether an entity actually is what it purports to be, and authorization is process in which you're deciding to allow or deny access to resources and yes for athorization You can use Zend_Acl

Comment: So I have to use Zend\Authentification (not Zend_Auth) in ZF2, right? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

To be able to do this you have to build or implement an ACL (Access Control List). You can also use a third party solution in combination with the earlier mentioned Zend_Auth (or any other authentication module). You can read more on Zend ACL here: [Zend ACL introduction](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.1/en/modules/zend.permissions.acl.intro.html)

You could for example also take a look at `BjyAuthorize`. This ACL module provides a complete authorization solution  for your application but depends on `ZfcUser` for user authentication and registration. It might be a good way to get started.

If you are done building or implementing `BjyAuthorize` you can easily tie your access permission checking to your routes (but there are many other ways). You can see how this works here [on the BjyAuthorize GitHub page](https://github.com/bjyoungblood/BjyAuthorize)

These modules will teach you a lot about how authentication and authorization can be build into your Zend Framework 2 application.